# Rename AWS Aurora Cluster using terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have an AWS Aurora Postgres Cluster (with a writer and a reader) created using terraform code. Now, because of some requirements, I need to change the name of the Aurora Cluster and its instances, which in turn also changes the reader and writer endpoint.

I wanted to know if there is a direct way to rename the Aurora resources already created by updating the terraform code.

I tried changing the `cluster_identifier` and instance `identifier` from (say) `aurora-storage-use1` to `aurora-db-use1` and ran the terraform plan. Tf plan shows the Cluster and the instances `must be replaced` which I do not want. I just need to rename the aurora cluster/instances.

The other option which I am aware is to

- Update the Cluster/Instance name from the AWS Console
- Import the changes to the terraform state file
- Update the underlying terraform code and change the names there
- Run terraform plan and make sure that no changes are to be applied

Can someone tell me if there is a straight fwd way to rename the aws resources via terraform?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like no. Workarounds listed in https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/507